# Trying to postMessage between two independent html files

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I am providing a product that shows 2 webpages over a two screen system (admittedtly although it is a two screen system it looks like they treat it as a single page they stretch across the 2 screens). I write both pages independently and want to use postMessage and addEventListener to communicate. I am not in control of launching these pages. They get installed on an environment and the environment puts both these pages in their own iFrame. This is how the created index file via the environment is creating the page with both pages on

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="root">
<iframe src="http://localhost:3005/somepath/topscreen">
    my html for top screen here
</iframe>
<section>
    <iframe src="http://localhost:3005/somepath/bottomscreen">
        my html for bottom screen here
    </iframe>
</section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The top screen does:

```
parent.addEventListener("message", messages.incomingMessage);
```

Bottom screen does

```
parent.postMessage("doSomething")
```

The communication is only ever one way, from bottom screen to top.

The error I get on postMessage is:

```
bottomscreen.js:5438 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://localhost:3005') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost:8090').
```

I am serving the environment on 8090 using http-server but it looks like the environment is running them on 3005.

Any ideas what I can do here?